# Java Web App for Multiple Devices

Tags: java

I am asking this question after going through similar questions like

1. [Presentation technology for multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897813/how-to-optimize-website-for-mobile-devices)
2. [How best to implement support for multiple devices in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881547/presentation-technology-for-multiple-devices)
3. [How to optimize website for mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480139/how-best-to-implement-support-for-multiple-devices-in-a-web-application)

After reading the replies I understand it best to go for a very light weight web site without using many fancy frameworks

I have zeroed down on using Spring MVC in the backend and jsp for the front end.

Having done this I need to get down to more specifics.

Suppose I want to render a datatable do I use plain jsp or can I use some framework like

[Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) . Will a framework provide me ease of coding and maintainability,functionality and at the same time will it render reasonably fast on mobile phone devices ?

The data table must have the ability to filter,sort,paginate etc.

I have used datatable component as an example. There could be other components as well like say trees, charts etc

Comment: If you've already chosen the backend, then please retitle and retag the question to reflect what you're trying to decide on, e.g. `[javascript]`.

Answer (score 0):

Personal opinion: keep your data separate from your views. For example, make all your data accessible as Json as well as through a Json based protocol (JsonRpc is nice simple protocol). This will reduce the amount of time/code needed for the server side. Then, you can develop multiple applications such as web/mobile applications. The abstraction defined by HTML web applications is now being copied by desktop applications (eg WPF) and of course mobile applications.